# i am presently using iphone 4s with r-sim

Tags: iphone

i wanted to upgrade my ios coz most of the apps are not supporting my present version . my present version is 6.0.1

i m using r-sim . it is not specifed for a particular carrier i can use any carrier network with this r-sim

i heard that 
if i update my phone through software update from itunes directly 
my phone gets locked and it goes into black list

how to update my phone .

please let me know how can i upgrade my ios

Comment: There is no reason to ask the same question twice if the original one gets put on hold. In such cases it's much better to edit the original question based on the comments you've received there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can update your phone as long as you're using an "outdated" R-SIM. You have to upgrade your R-SIM first, but I don't think there is already an available version for iOS 9.0.1. That's the nuisance of using special SIMs like that. If you update it with the latest iOS, it won't be blacklisted (you will still be able to use it), but it will be locked to the carrier it is originally locked to.

Another way to update is to jailbreak your iPhone but just like R-SIM, you can't always get the jailbroken iOS with the same version as the non-jailbroken version.

The best way to keep your iPhone have the latest iOS version is to buy a factory-unlocked iPhone.